# how to apply css class to mvccontrib grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, mvccontrib

I am using mvccontrib grid in asp.net mvc(C#) application.

How can i apply css class to the grid thats created for the mvccontrib grid Attributes?

I am looking to construct like:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="usertable">....</table>
```

By default, the mvccontrib grid has the class "grid". I need to change it to my custom css class

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Html.Grid(x).Columns(col => {}).Attributes(@class => "usertable");
```

By the way MvcContrib's Grid should have full intellisense so you should see all the available methods when you type "." (dot).